# How to select from mysql before inserting into mysql in express

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I want to insert a user into a mysql database, but before I do that, I want to select the latest uid from mysql, run a custom function `generateUid(uid)` on it, to generate a new uid and **then** I want to add the user.

I know, how to add the user, but I don't know how to cascade the two steps:

```js
const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());

const generateUid = (uid) => {
    // My custom stuff here
    return uid;
}

app.post("/generateUser", function (req, res) {
  
  /*
  #TODO:
   - query: SELECT uid FROM users ORDER BY uid DESC LIMIT 1
   - const fetchedUid = query_result
   - run custom function generateUid(fetchedUid)
   - after that run the following INSERT INTO...
  */

  const { name, mail, tel, street, zip, city, birthday } = req.body;

  if ((name, mail, tel, street, zip, city, birthday)) {
    query =
      "INSERT INTO users (name, mail, tel, street, zip, city, birthday, date_checkin, uid) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,NOW(),?)";
    inserts = [
      name,
      mail,
      tel,
      street,
      zip,
      city,
      birthday,
      uid
    ];
    connection.execute(query, inserts, (err) => {
      if (err) {
        return res.send(err);
      } else {
        return res.send("User added");
      }
    });
  } else {
    res.send("Invalid User");
  }
});
```

Comment: Why are you using an archaic and insecure API that was deprecated almost a decade ago?

Comment: Even this is an off topic question, thank you for the feedback though. You mean body-parser?

Comment: You don't need to escape anything when you use parameters in the query.

Comment: Why are you generating the uid yourself instead of using `AUTO_INCREMENT`?

Comment: Because the uid has a custom required scheme

Comment: Anyway, ths answer is simple: You execute the `SELECT` query, then in its callback function you execute the `INSERT` query.

Comment: I removed the escapement functions from the question post. What is outdated, I don't know.

Comment: Thank you @Barmar - I added my approach in an answer.

Answer (score 1):

From the comments I figured it out. If you have any feedback, let me know:

```js
app.post("/generateUser", function (req, res) {
  connection.query(
    `SELECT uid FROM users ORDER BY uid DESC LIMIT 1`,
    (err, result) => {
      if (err) {
        return res.send(err);
      } else {
        const uid = generateUid(result[0].uid);

        const { name, mail, tel, street, zip, city, birthday } = req.body;

        if ((name, mail, tel, street, zip, city, birthday)) {
          query =
            "INSERT INTO users (name, mail, tel, street, zip, city, birthday, date_checkin, uid) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,NOW(),?)";
          inserts = [name, mail, tel, street, zip, city, birthday, uid];
          connection.execute(query, inserts, (err) => {
            if (err) {
              return res.send(err);
            } else {
              return res.send("User added");
            }
          });
        } else {
          res.send("Invalid User");
        }
      }
    }
  );
});
```